# ELI5 how to install an external library like curl?

Tags: c++, c, linker, codeblocks, toolchain

Hi guys I've been coding in C/C++ for a little while now but I'm struggling to install external librarys. As an example I wanted to install and use curl but I apparently have no clue what I'm doing. If anyone could be kind enough to go step by step on how to install it/other libraries it would be amazing.

Thank you!

edit: I am using mingw and codeblock

Answer (score 0):

If using Visual Studio: [**cURL NuGet**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/curl/)

I just found out today at my job that Visual C++ supports Nuget, and used it to load the [**Boost C++ Library**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/boost/) a piece at a time (using only the pieces I needed) ... **huge** time saver ...

Comment: Forgot to mention it but I use codeblock with mingw

Comment: sorry ... just saw you _did_ include the tag codeblocks. I do see package manager mingw-get, but - as you probably already know - support for an msys-curl appears to be more than sketchy.